# Pusher not triggering on Heroku Rails app, but works fine on localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, pusher

I am learning Pusher on a Ruby on Rails app and have it setup where user clicks a button, it submits a form to update an object, then triggers a Pusher event that sends an alert and changes the background color for all windows listening on that channel.

I have the site running on my local server localhost:3000 and on Heroku. On localhost:3000, this works like a charm - when I have windows open running the site both locally and on Heroku, and I click the button on the local site, all windows receive the alert and update the background color.

HOWEVER, when I try the same thing on Heroku, none of the windows receive the alert or change color. I've looked at the Debug Console on Pusher and it shows that a connection is made, but it does not show an API request sent:

```
Subscribed    35329.28868505   Channel:  client-open    23:52:33
Connection    35329.28868505   Origin:   http://testing-pusher.herokuapp.com    23:52:33
Disconnection  35303.28886132  Channels: client-open, Lifetime: 107.70291038s   23:52:32
```

Per [Heroku's help page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pusher), I've installed the pusher gem and the addon.

Here is my trigger that runs in my `switches#update`:

```
@switch.update(color: params[:switch][:color])
Pusher['client-open'].trigger('new_message', {:color => @switch.color})
```

The listener/binding that runs on application.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {
    Pusher.log = function(message) {
        if (window.console && window.console.log) {
            window.console.log(message);
        }
    };

    var pusher = new Pusher('my_pusher_key'); // This has my actual key in it
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('client-open');
    channel.bind('new_message', function(data) {
        alert("I'm going to change your background color to #"+data.color);
        $("#appended").append("I'm going to change your background color to "+data.color);
        $(".color").css('background-color', '#'+data.color);
});

// Some useful Pusher debug msgs
pusher.connection.bind('connecting', function() {
    $('div#status').text('Connecting to Pusher...');
});

pusher.connection.bind('connected', function() {
    $('div#status').text('Connected to Pusher!');
});
    pusher.connection.bind('failed', function() {
      $('div#status').text('Connection to Pusher failed :(');
    });
    channel.bind('subscription_error', function(status) {
      $('div#status').text('Pusher subscription_error');
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have these two scripts in the header of the same file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://js.pusherapp.com/2.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
```

How can I get Pusher to properly trigger on Heroku?

EDIT: Here are the Heroku logs. No errors that I can tell:

```
2014-05-07T18:40:46.291870+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/switches/1 host=testing-pusher.herokuapp.com request_id=f3f9e17c-086b-4639-88ba-4a406828c4e7 fwd="24.20.217.80" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=72ms status=302 bytes=942
2014-05-07T18:40:46.224270+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PATCH "/switches/1" for 24.20.217.80 at 2014-05-07 18:40:46 +0000
2014-05-07T18:40:46.224278+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PATCH "/switches/1" for 24.20.217.80 at 2014-05-07 18:40:46 +0000
2014-05-07T18:40:46.227649+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SwitchesController#update as HTML
2014-05-07T18:40:46.415613+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 24.20.217.80 at 2014-05-07 18:40:46 +0000
2014-05-07T18:40:46.455745+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 19.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
2014-05-07T18:40:46.230175+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SwitchesController#update as HTML
2014-05-07T18:40:46.424400+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SwitchesController#show as HTML
2014-05-07T18:40:46.451080+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered switches/_form.html.haml (7.4ms)
2014-05-07T18:40:46.230262+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nqhkV37GG6ym+pM7j+Bdxh3aBltTLfNpPa6cnE6b92U=", "switch"=>{"color"=>"c4b6c2"}, "commit"=>"push me", "id"=>"1"}
2014-05-07T18:40:46.230298+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nqhkV37GG6ym+pM7j+Bdxh3aBltTLfNpPa6cnE6b92U=", "switch"=>{"color"=>"c4b6c2"}, "commit"=>"push me", "id"=>"1"}
2014-05-07T18:40:46.287569+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://testing-pusher.herokuapp.com/
2014-05-07T18:40:46.287617+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://testing-pusher.herokuapp.com/
2014-05-07T18:40:46.287866+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 57ms (ActiveRecord: 8.2ms)
2014-05-07T18:40:46.287875+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 57ms (ActiveRecord: 8.2ms)
2014-05-07T18:40:46.409915+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 24.20.217.80 at 2014-05-07 18:40:46 +0000
2014-05-07T18:40:46.423250+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SwitchesController#show as HTML
2014-05-07T18:40:46.451349+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered switches/show.html.haml within layouts/application (12.7ms)
2014-05-07T18:40:46.446554+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered switches/_form.html.haml (7.4ms)
2014-05-07T18:40:46.452492+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 19.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
2014-05-07T18:40:46.451312+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered switches/show.html.haml within layouts/application (12.7ms)
```

EDIT 2: Issue was just missing Pusher credentials on heroku. Added those via ENV and it worked fine. [See comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483960/pusher-not-triggering-on-heroku-rails-app-but-works-fine-on-localhost3000#comment36417889_23514329)

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing any errors or messages in the Heroku logs?

Also, have you tried a simple test-case on Heroku that does nothing else but send a message via the Pusher gem?

Comment: No errors on Heroku logs. I've added the relevant logs above.

I haven't tried sending a message. From looking at the Debug Console, the API request isn't even happening. I will try that anyway though.

Comment: How did you get on with a simple test-case app that does nothing but send a message via Pusher?

Comment: Got it working. It was missing env vars on `environment/production.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the Pusher app credential.

When you create the pusher app, you can select the cluster which represents local region cluster.
For example, 'ap3' means Asian Pacific (Tokyo) and 'eu' means 'Europe'.

So you'd better to change your Pusher app when deploy to server.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the show, but if anyone else runs into this....
For me, I had to remove these from my config

```js
const pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: 'APP_ID',
  key: 'APP_KEY',
  secret: process.env.PUSHER_SECRET,
  cluster: 'us2',
  // these two were causing pusher.trigger to not work on deployed server
  // useTLS: true
  // encrypted: true
})
```